Apple Wallet webService notifications
I'm getting lost here with what could be the solution to send background push in iOS
I currently have a webService to create a storeCard, everything seems to be working fine, the pass is created, when the user adds it i get the pushToken and save it in my database.
The confusion starts when i try to send a notification, since the push token doesn't work for both the development and production environments.
To generate the pass i'm using @walletpass/pass-js and in summary it signs it using these values:
const signerCertPem = await getSecretValue(process.env.APPLE_PASS_CERT_SECRET);
const signerKeyPem = await getSecretValue(process.env.APPLE_PASS_PRIVATE_KEY_SECRET); 
const passphrase = await getSecretValue(process.env.SIGNER_KEY_PASSPHRASE_SECRET);

    const template = new Template('storeCard', {
      passTypeIdentifier: process.env.PASS_TYPE_IDENTIFIER,
      teamIdentifier: process.env.APPLE_TEAM_ID,
      organizationName: '',
      description: '',
      backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
      labelColor: 'rgb(255, 255, 255)',
      logoText: '', // Empty logoText to use the logo image
      sharingProhibited: true,
      appLaunchURL: '',
      associatedStoreIdentifiers: [], 
    });

template.setCertificate(signerCertPem);
template.setPrivateKey(signerKeyPem, passphrase);

    const pass = template.createPass({
      serialNumber: userId,
      authenticationToken: authenticationToken,
      webServiceURL: process.env.WEB_SERVICE_URL,
      description: 'Pleassurie Sugarless Club',
    });

As mentioned, pass is created, the user adds it and then i get the pushToken with which i try to send a push notification:
 const isProduction = process.env.ENV_MODE === 'prod';

        console.log(`APNs Provider running in ${isProduction ? 'production' : 'development'} mode`);

        
        const service = new apn.Provider({
            token: {
                key: keyBuffer,  // Pass only the key as a Buffer
                keyId: process.env.APPLE_APN_KEY_ID,
                teamId: process.env.APPLE_TEAM_ID,
            },
            production: isProduction, 
            debug: true
        });

        
        const notification = new apn.Notification();
        notification.topic = process.env.PASS_TYPE_IDENTIFIER;
        notification.payload = {}; 

After running i receive an error:
ERROR   Failed response: 
{
    "reason": "BadDeviceToken"
}

I'm starting to wonder maybe i generated some certificates wrong, is there any correlation between the pass pem certificates and the apn .p8 that i'm using?
As mentioned, tried both environments, even pasted the pushToken in Apple Developer Tool where it validates the token -> Device Token is invalid
I use firebase messaging to get tokens for push notifications, but from what i've read, the messaging notifications token and the pushToken from wallet are different, so not really sure how else to debug. also tried re-installing both from test flight and xcode(clean build as well)

I've just finished my Apple Wallet pass notification sending thing yesterday :) I've noticed that you've omitted the part of the code where notification is actually being sent. I have a hunch the the answer to this situation is there :) in particular, what are you using as the device token?
